# How to store a list as output of function in a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to store in a column as a list the results of a function taking its input from a tibble.
I was thinking to use a vectorized version with mutate from tidyverse as follow:

```
test <- tibble(a=rep(1,10), b=seq(1,10))
 return_list <- function(x){
  return(c("a1" = x, "a2"= x + x))
}
return_list_v <- Vectorize(return_list) 
test  %>% mutate(results=return_list_v(a))
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Erreur : Column `results` must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 20
```

Is there something that could be done to make this example work?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIMPLIFY=FALSE` keeps the output to be a list, instead of making a matrix.

```
test <- tibble(a=rep(1,10), b=seq(1,10))
return_list <- function(x){
  return(c("a1" = x, "a2"= x + x))
}
return_list_v <- Vectorize(return_list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE) 
test  %>% mutate(results=return_list_v(a))
```